# WSO2-APIM-CLI(Import/Export) tool list-apis functions only returns 25 items in the results

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I tried following steps in importing/exporitng apis from wso2am-2.2.0

1. Downloading and copy api-import-export-2.2.0-v4.war file to the /repository/deployment/server/webapps folder
2. Downloading and extracting apimcli-1.1.0-linux-x64.tar.gz to a preferred location a linux machine
3. Adding named mylocalhost to apimcli tool:

> ```
> ./apimcli add-env -n mylocalhost \
>     --registration https://localhost:9443/client-registration/v0.13/register \
>     --apim https://localhost:9443 \
>     --token https://localhost:8243/token \
>     --import-export https://localhost:9443/api-import-export-2.5.0-v1 \
>     --admin https://localhost:9443/api/am/admin/v0.13 \
>     --api_list https://localhost:9443/api/am/publisher/v0.13/apis \
>     --app_list https://localhost:9443/api/am/store/v0.13/applications
> ```

4. Requesting a list of all apis created on environment mylocalhost using following command,

> `./apimcli --insecure list apis -e mylocalhost -u admin -p admin`

**I was returned an output as below, but always it only returns 25 items, even though actual API count is more than 25.**

***Can someone please tell me why?***

<<<**Output**>>>

```html
Environment: mylocalhost
No. of APIs: 25
+------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
|                NAME                | VERSION |                   CONTEXT                    |   STATUS   | PROVIDER |                  ID                  |
+------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
| DevOps_Test1                       |     001 | /devops1                                     | PUBLISHED  | admin    | f2ca6d69-6654-4c66-8bf7-c41f506e85d9 |
| DevOps_Test2                       | v1.0.0  | /devops2                                     | PUBLISHED  | admin    | b4a6c2a4-44b6-416d-8f33-9d278ee8cd55 | 
| DevOps_Test3                       |     001 | /devops3                                     | CREATED    | admin    | d50addce-3ee6-40a1-9d68-0147625178dc |
| DevOps_Test4                       |     001 | /devops4                                     | PUBLISHED  | admin    | 9f5d3c9c-f4e9-42db-86e8-ab7d0caeb58e |
| DevOps_Test5                       | v1      | /devops5                                     | PUBLISHED  | admin    | e5b2938c-4586-4a92-add2-e1fa02841b34 |
| DevOps_Test6                       |     001 | /devops6                                     | PUBLISHED  | admin    | 09234299-34e4-4603-8aa1-08082e47b73e |
| DevOps_Test7                       |     001 | /devops7                                     | PUBLISHED  | admin    | ff16e906-e345-4c48-9e5e-466651d6f8c6 |
| DevOps_Test8                       |     001 | /devops8                                     | PUBLISHED  | admin    | 60763f04-2178-40e2-bf11-12a5d6d536fa |
| DevOps_Test9                       |     001 | /devops9                                     | PUBLISHED  | admin    | 640f8585-0b2c-4c41-8ba5-0d5c6a93a66a |
| DevOps_Test10                      |     001 | /devops10                                    | PUBLISHED  | admin    | 61132bca-76c5-4cf9-b882-79c0a53567fb |
| DevOps_Test11                      |     001 | /devops11                                    | PUBLISHED  | admin    | 552e4954-5937-44b5-8c94-332a9358f026 |
| DevOps_Test12                      | 1.0.0   | /api/devops12                                | PUBLISHED  | admin    | 54b3e604-7753-46aa-8363-839db7df1b22 |
| DevOps_Test13                      | 1.0.0   | /api/devops13                                | PUBLISHED  | admin    | a1be533f-8fba-4d4f-be35-9d40141f7f49 |
| DevOps_Test14                      |     001 | /devops14                                    | PUBLISHED  | admin    | 8c00d02f-dcbf-4477-8f4e-e45ae33ed216 |
| DevOps_Test14                      |     002 | /devops14                                    | PUBLISHED  | admin    | 79fe53b0-750b-4198-be44-10f68b000dc7 |
| DevOps_Test14                      |     003 | /devops14                                    | PUBLISHED  | admin    | b959d0dd-605b-4c5c-aad7-e956542cb63c |
| DevOps_Test15                      |     001 | /devops15                                    | PUBLISHED  | admin    | d1002f45-faf0-466e-a78a-c42ed3bd4df9 |
| DevOps_Test16                      | 1.0.0   | /devops16                                    | PUBLISHED  | admin    | 9b69d553-b22e-45de-8711-317e7e93abe7 |
| DevOps_Test17                      |       1 | /devops17                                    | PROTOTYPED | admin    | 31a4bae4-470c-4226-9d2b-d6cc4b850f0e |
| DevOps_Test18                      | 1.0.0   | /devops18                                    | PROTOTYPED | admin    | c052a322-5493-4077-a826-0bed56e19d51 |
| DevOps_Test19                      |     001 | /devops19                                    | PUBLISHED  | yasas    | 1322fbab-c0be-4fa8-9d79-5bc46b7ceee7 |
| DevOps_Test20                      |     001 | /devops20                                    | PUBLISHED  | yasas    | 912ebb5c-dbb7-4ac4-99b0-3942104af0c6 |
| DevOps_Test21                      |     001 | /devops21                                    | PUBLISHED  | yasas    | df999477-c209-470e-94a0-ab26e78b6f69 |
| DevOps_Test22                      |     001 | /devops22                                    | PUBLISHED  | yasas    | c0009f59-4245-455e-b00a-43f671af4206 |
| DevOps_Test23                      |     001 | /devops23                                    | PUBLISHED  | yasas    | 51819611-f515-444c-a90b-8b02d766ba0c |
+------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because API Manager list API returns 25 as the default limit of returned API list and it seems like pagination are not handled in API Manager CLI tool. As a workaround add limit `query` parameter to the `api_list_endpoint` url in `main_config.yaml`. main_config.yaml found in `/home/<user>/.wso2apimcli` location.

ex: `api_list_endpoint: https://localhost:9443/api/am/publisher/v0.12/apis?limit=30`

Comment: Great !!! Thanks a lot Lakshman. I increased the limit={value} to 50 and was able to get a list of all apis in my APIM instance.
Thank you very much !